# TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm testing a new app in Flask but I don't know what went wrong.

I created **toy.py** and added a class to it.

```
class Toy:
    count = 1

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.id = Toy.count
        Toy.count += 1
```

In the **app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from toy import Toy


app = Flask(__name__)


spiderman = Toy(name='spiderman')
superman = Toy(name='superman')
bathman = Toy(name='bathman')

toys = [spiderman, superman, bathman]

@app.route('/toys',)
def toys():
    return render_template('toys.html', toys=toys)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the HTML file I was trying to loop true

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
TOYS PAGE
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<ul>
    {% for toy in toys %}
    <li>{{ toy.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
**{% for toy in toys %}
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable**
```

Answer (score 4):

You are redefining the name `toys`.

First in,

```py
toys = [spiderman, superman, bathman]
```

Second in,

```py
@app.route('/toys',)
def toys():
    return render_template('toys.html', toys=toys)
```

So in the end `toys` is a function. Maybe name the `Toy` list as `_toys`